# Converting Excel formula to VBA add-in (FILTER)

Tags: excel, vba, filter, excel-formula, xlookup

I have this formula in a cell, it effectively works a bit like xlookup but actually returns all the matches as a CSV string instead of just the first match

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER('[myFile.xlsx]ForLookUp'!$K:$K,'[myFile.xlsx]ForLookUp'!$N:$N=A2))

Where

- Column K is where the returned values will be pulled from,
- Column N is where the data range to find matches in lives
- and A2 is the cell that contains the 'key' I'm trying to match

This works fine but I want to convert it to VBA so I can add it to my Add-In file and reuse

I thought it was going to be relatively simple but I don't think either TEXTJOIN or FILTER exist as-is in VBA? I've been around the web trying to find answers but have not ready found something which works for me.

Ideally for the add-in, both the ranges and the key would be params passed to the routine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Regard

Comment: If you have the functions available, then they should be present in VBA as methods of the `Worksheetfunction` object.

Comment: Thanks - all these years and didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your VBA code base

```
Function textfilter(dataRange As Range, filter As Variant)
  textfilter = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(", ", True, WorksheetFunction.filter(dataRange, filter))
End Function
```

and call it in the cell like this

```
=textfilter('[myFile.xlsx]ForLookUp'!$K:$K,'[myFile.xlsx]ForLookUp'!$N:$N=A2)
```